# Laravel 7 Yajra datatable NOT responsive

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, datatable, yajra-datatable

I'm using Yajra datatable from a weblesson tutorial.

All is working great, but the data-table is NOT responsive.

I included this code :

```
$('#user_table').DataTable({
  responsive: true,
```

Thanks to Omer :

I added two CDN :

```
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.1.1/css/rowGroup.bootstrap4.min.css" />
```

and I REMOVE this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
```

All is working great now.

Like you can on this photo, my table is responsive :

[image]

**EDIT :**

Thanks to Omer :

I added two CDN :

```
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.1.1/css/rowGroup.bootstrap4.min.css" />
```

and I REMOVE this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" />
```

All is working great now.

Thank you.

Comment: in https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/ url you will see other examples. What do you want exactly?

Comment: You probably want to this: https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/immediateShow.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bootstrap `table-responsive` add `overflow-x: auto` style at your tag. So bootstrap responsive is working on your site. If you want to datatable responsive, you must add the extension:
https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive

*Responsive is an extension for DataTables that resolves that problem by optimising the table's layout for different screen sizes through the dynamic insertion and removal of columns from the table.*

Comment: Hi, Thank you.  I was reading your link's page when you replied.  Indeed, I have to install the responsive files (CSS and JS).  I did it and that's better, THANK YOU.  I still have a problem, the display is not correct, I edit my original post to show.  Thank you agian.

Comment: I did one minute ago

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted your code **as is** in a new file, opened it and tested it : no problem

[image]

---

### Now it is too easy to tell you it works, the problem is on your side...

So i did a few tests :

1. Firefox 75 => OK
2. Edge 81.0.416.68 => OK
3. Even IE 11.778.18362.0

Seems to me that this has to be more of a browser-side issue (cache, browser-extensions blocking JS or CSS properties...)

Maybe try on another browser (a portable one to avoid stacking on your machine...)

**But this probably has nothing to do stackoverflow as this isn't provoked by code or code misunderstanding.**

Comment: Hi, thank you, I had to add   <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.1.1/css/rowGroup.bootstrap4.min.css" /> without them, I had no responsive.  Thank you again.

Comment: You're right, the site was responsive, NOT the data-table.  Thank you anayway to have tried.